# Trying to get to 1234567 with three levers of different function

Tags: mathematics

I am trying to get 1234567.
There are three levers, lever a, lever b, and lever c.
Lever a shifts 1234567 to the right.
So it would look like 2345671.
Lever b swaps the third and fifth number.
So it would look like 1254367.
Lever c shifts 1234567 to the left.
So it would look like 7123456.
I currently have 1234657 how do i get to 1234567?
I've been trying for a while and I can't get it.

Comment: You can forget about lever c as it amounts to pull lever a 6 times.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier as long as we are not counting the number of lever pulls.

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 5):

First, note that

> Up to using lever a appropriately, what lever b really allows you is to swap **any two** digits that are one place apart.

Therefore

> you can first have the $5$ cycle to its final destination: $$1234657\stackrel{45}{\to} 1235647\stackrel{25}{\to} 1532647\stackrel{75}{\to} 1732645\stackrel{65}{\to} 1732546$$
>  and then the $6$:
>  $$1732546\stackrel{67}{\to} 1632547\stackrel{62}{\to} 1236547\stackrel{64}{\to} 1234567$$

Answer (score 3):

Same idea as @Arnuad, but in $5$ moves:

> $$1234657\stackrel{51}{\to} 5234617\stackrel{53}{\to} 3254617\stackrel{56}{\to} 3264517\stackrel{63}{\to} 6234517\stackrel{61}{\to} 1234567$$

Answer (score 2):

The fewest number of lever pulls is 12, of which 5 are swaps (b) and 7 are shifts (a and c). I verified this by computer.

> 1234657, Swap
>     1264357, Left
>     2643571, Swap
>     2653471, 2xRight
>     7126534, Swap
>     7156234, Right
>     4715623, Swap
>     4765123, Right
>     3476512, Swap
>     3456712, 2xRight
>     1234567

The way this works is that

> the incorrect pair 65 jumps to the left, over the 34 pair, and then over the 12 pair, so that it ends up at the other side of the 7. You are essentially left with 1234765 which can be fixed with one more swap.